# What does "pl" or "p" mean in a version number?

Tags: versioning, abbreviation

In PHP's [`version_compare`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php) function, `pl` or `p` are the only strings in a version number that are evaluated to be later than the numbered versions.  Which means that when comparing version numbers,

`1.5` < `1.6-beta` < `1.6` < `1.6.1` < `1.6-pl`

My question is, what does `pl` or `p` stand for in this context?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`p` and `pl` stand for "patch" or "patch level."

The example version numbers that I gave in the question highlight a bit of a quirk with using PHP's `version_compare` function.  Most strings are evaluated lower than a number, and the absence of a number (such as the third position in `1.6`) is evaluated to the number 0.  However, `p` and `pl` are evaluated higher than a number.  Therefore, if you start with version `1.6`, and you'd like to release a patch version for `1.6` with the intent of releasing `1.6.1` in the future, your patched version should be labeled `1.6.0-pl`.  Otherwise, `1.6.1` will be seen as older than `1.6-pl`.